# Create an archive .zip from file stream where file mode is Read

Tags: c#, zip, filestream, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

There is a zip folder and it contains an XML file. This is been retried from a service as

```
return File.Open("location", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

Now in the UI, when the user clicks a link, he should get an archive .zip folder and this file should be available in that user's downloaded folder with the XML file.

Currently I am trying using `ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile()`. It creates a zip folder but when I try to extract it manually, it says empty compressed folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **System.IO.Compression** library and use **ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, ExtractionPath)**
This might help.

For more help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

Comment: This gives me the file extracted from ZipArchiveEntry, but i want the output itself as zipped folder

Comment: If you want to zip up a folder, then use  **ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)**.
If you want to unzip a folder, then use **ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, ExtractionPath)**

If you want to do any kind of operation related to compression, then please go through link which I mentioned in the answer. This might help

Comment: My requirement is i have a Stream. If i give it a ExtractToFile, it is downloading as .xml file. But i want Stream to be converted directly as a zip file

Comment: Apology for late reply, but you can do lengthy procedure, but I guess it will work.
1. Store that string into file. 2. Create zip of it 3. Do unzip of it.